# spinner in input number hides on Mobile and tablets

Tags: html, css

I'm having a trouble displaying up/down spinner on mobile and tablet devices. 
I have already written some Css to do the trick but it doesn't work :

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {  

   opacity: 1 !important;

}
```

How should I display the spinners of input number on mobiles and tablets ?

Thanks

Comment: just use media query. refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/35605310/5383669 and use it as you want in any resolution.

Answer (score 0):

try to this with media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
    input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
    input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
      -webkit-appearance: none; 
      margin: 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. By the way , i'm trying to make spinners to be displayed on tablets and mobiles and not hiding them.